# Creating Java Calendar, basic parameters

Tags: java, web-services, calendar

I would like to send a Java Calendar object over a web service (soap). I notice that this kind of object is too complex and there should be a better method to send the same information.

What are the basic attributes that should be sended over the web service, so the client can create a Java Calendar out of this attributes?

I'm guessing: TimeZone, Date, and Time?

Also, how can the client recreate the Calendar based on those attributes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In fact I would go for `Timezone tz` (timezone the calendar was expressed in), `Locale loc` (used for data representation purpose) and `long time` (UTC time) if you want exactly the same object.

In most uses the time is enough though, the receiver will express it with his own timezone and locale.

Comment: Use the JavaX binding to XMLGregorianCalendar.  Don't need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the `Calendar` instance that you would like to send is of type `java.util.GregorianCalendar`. In that case, you could just use `xsd:dateTime`. For SOAP, Java will usually bind that to a `javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar` instance.

Translating between GregorianCalendarand XMLGregorianCalendar:

- GregorianCalendar -> XMLGregorianCalendar: `javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newXMLGregorianCalendar(GregorianCalendar)`
- XMLGregorianCalendar -> GregorianCalendar: `XMLGregorianCalendar.toGregorianCalendar()`

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.GregorianCalendar`, [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a long value.

```
java.util.Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()
```

This returns the long value for the date. That value can be used to construct java.util.Date or a Calendar.

Comment: Using a count-from-epoch is clumsy, risky, and ambiguous. What resolution - whole seconds, millis, microseconds, nanoseconds? Which of [the eighteen epoch reference dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) used by notable systems? Using java.time classes and standard ISO 8601 formats is simpler, easier to debug, and less error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Use plain text, in UTC, in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
Instant.now().toString()
```

> 2018-01-23T01:23:45.123456Z

```
Instant.parse( "2018-01-23T01:23:45.123456Z" )
```

## ISO 8601

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard is a well-designed practical set of textual formats for representing date-time values.

> 2018-01-14T03:57:05.744850Z

The java.time classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. The `ZonedDateTime` class wisely extends the standard to append the name of a time zone in square brackets.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
String output = zdt.toString() ;
```

> 2018-01-13T19:56:26.318984-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]

## java.time

The `java.util.Calendar` class is part of the troublesome old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. These legacy classes are an awful mess, and should be avoided.

Now supplanted by the modern industry-leading java.time classes.

## UTC

Generally best to communicate a moment using [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) rather than a particular time zone.

The standard format for a UTC moment is `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSSSSSSSZ` where the `T` separates the year-month-day from the hour-minute-second. The `Z` on the end is short for `Zulu` and means `UTC`.

### `Instant`

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

> 2018-01-14T03:57:05.744850Z

If a particular time zone is crucial, use a `ZonedDateTime` as shown above.

## Parsing

These strings in standard format can be parsed to instantiate java.time objects.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2018-01-14T03:57:05.744850Z" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse( "2018-01-13T19:56:26.318984-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]" ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time (JSR 310) classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).